# Installing Leptess in the WASM project

Tags: rust, webassembly

I'm trying to add the `leptess` lib to the `Cargo.toml` file and I'm getting error:

```
failed to run custom build command for `tesseract-sys v0.5.7`
```

OS: MacOS 12
Project platform: `wasm32-unknown-unknown`

Comment: Sounds like `tesseract` (and therefore `leptess`) don't support the Wasm platform.

Comment: `tesseract` is a Rust binding to a C++ library. AFAIK the bindings are not compiled to WASM with rustc, so you'll probably need to use C++ tools to interact with it.